# When to use MassTransit IRequestClient and when IBus.Send

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

I'm using `MassTransit` with `MediatR` library.

in the controller I'm using mediator to send message

```
List<Car> cars = await _mediator.Send(new GetCarDataQuery());
```

GetCarDataQuery will end up in the GetCarDataQueryHandler and as a result it will return list of car objects.

All good but If I for example get rid of `MediatR` library what would be the equivalent of sending message as above.
Using `MassTransit` IBus like `_bus.Send(new MyCommand())` or using `IRequestClient`?

As far I understand `IRequestClient` would be syncronous call and _bus will be async call with placing message on the queue? From this I think I need to use `_bus.Send<MyCommand>()` but I'm not sure how to receive response back from the consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a response, you should use `IRequestClient<T>`.

If you need to fire-and-forget a message, use `Publish`.

The [MassTransit Mediator](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html) is documented, and you can watch various [YouTube videos](https://youtu.be/97PXJIrGnes).